# Change shape in tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have a custom loss function (in keras) which receives as an input two batches, so their shapes (being the same for both) usually is (batch_size 128, 128, 3) being an image. Now, I want to perform two operations, which have the followings shapes:

- (batch_size, 128, 128)
- (batch_size)

Now, what I'd like to do is to sum the two tensor, but obviously I can't, so the idea is simple: expand the second to have the same shapes of the first, copying the single values in the other vacant positions.

How can I do that, considering it's a loss function?

Note: I already tried to reduce the first tensor and sum that with the second as scalars, but this solution doesn't work as I want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to broadcast the same values multiple times, this is already supported. You just need to make sure your dimensions are lined up for broadcasting.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[[1,2],[2,3]],[[3,4],[4,5]],[[5,6],[6,7]]])
b = tf.constant([1,2,3])

print(a + b[:,None,None])
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing something similar:
`a = tf.expand_dims(a, axis=-1)
a = tf.extend_dims(a, axis=-1)`